# Codeigniter - Using or_where_in along with like, produces unexpected results

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my codeigniter query

```
$this->db->like('nombre', $search); //$search= "some string"
$this->db->or_where_in('idAuto', $autos); //$autos= array('x','y','z');
$this->db->or_where_in('idMarca', $marcas); //$marcas= array('x','y','z');
$this->db->get('servicios');
```

This is the query string generated

```
SELECT * FROM (`servicios`) WHERE `idAuto` IN ('2', '9', '16') AND `idMarca` IN ('1', '2', '3') AND `nombre` LIKE '%a%'
```

And this is what i expected:

```
SELECT * FROM (`servicios`) WHERE `idAuto` IN ('2', '9', '16') AND `idMarca` IN ('1', '2', '3') OR`nombre` LIKE '%a%'
```

I tested also with or_like and got the same result

```
$this->db->or_like('nombre', $search); //$search= "some string"
```

Anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this:

```
$this->db->like('nombre', $search);
```

to this

```
$this->db->or_like('nombre', $search);
```

you can try with a trick like this:

```
$this->db->or_where("`nombre` LIKE '%".$searcg."%'", NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt edit perfectly the question, i tested or_like too

Comment: can you print the query when you use or_like? thanks @JoseFaro

Comment: the result query is exactly the same, if I use like or or_like, and whether i place it before or after the or_where_in clauses